# Python Script to create vm on Oracle Virtual box in Windows

Tags: python, windows, virtualbox

Can we write a python script to create a vm in oracle virtual machine in windows? If so can where can I get pointers to implement this?

Comment: The oracle tag is meant for use only for Oracle DB. See the tag info page and the first box there: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle/info

Comment: check this: https://pypi.org/project/pyvbox/


I guess you were meaning Oracle VirtualBox

Comment: Yes I meant oracle virtual box :).